# Переход на новую активность по нажатию BottomBar

Tags: java, android

При нажатии на кнопку в нижнем баре, у меня должен быть переход на новую активность, на которой создается фрагмент, ну и соответсвенно BottomBar пропадает, как решить даннуюю проблему?

Правка:При нажатии на кнопку, происходит переход на сущность с SlidingBar

У меня есть 2 варианта 
1.При нажатии на кнопку переход на новую активность и там 2 фрагмента, но это неправильный способ.

2.При нажатии на кнопку менять разметку активности(в которой нажали на кнопку) и создавать на основе этой активности и новой разметки фрагменты, но тут также придется заново инициализировать BottomBar.

3. ????

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

У вас 2 варианта:

1. Вам не нужно при нажатии на кнопку переходить в другую актвити. Отображайте фрагмент в текущей активити.
2. Добавьте BottomBar во вторую активити

Comment: Как будет правильней?Потому-что если мы создаем новую активити - это прям чувствуется.

Comment: Правильный вариант конечно первый

Comment: Ну, тогда мне нужно будет менять разметку активности основной, и в разметке заново создавать BottomBar, тут уже идет проблема отображения цвета(на каком вкладке находишься), и не только отображения, но еще и заного инициализировать надо будет ?

Comment: @АнтонМартынов, по идее делается так: в активити 2 контейнера - для фрагментов + для нижней панели с кнопками. По нажатию кнопки отображается фрагмент в верхнем контейнере.

Comment: Понимаете, у меня при нажатии на кнопку,должен открыться SlidingTab, и у меня 2 выбора как я понимаю, либо через новую активность либо через смену разметки, как мне быть,посоветуйте пожалуйста.

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: @АнтонМартынов, если у вас по кнопке должен открываться экран с совсем другими элементами навигации, т.е. нажатая кнопка не должна на нём отображаться то вам нужно новую актвити запускать